# How to update TabRow Indicator with LazyListState in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I can't show the app due to company policies, but pretty much I have a Lazy List that will animateToItem when a tab is selected, but also when the User scrolls on the Lazy List, the tab indicator needs to be updated as well according to the corresponding section and tab the User is on. I got the text color to update upon scroll, but not really sure how to update the indicator? It seems like the indicator is only launching upon recomposition.

```
    @Composable
    private fun MyTab(
       tabs: List<MyTabs>,
       lazyListState: LazyListState
    ){
      var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
      val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
      TabRow(
       selectedTabIndex = selectedIndex,
       indicator = { tabPositions ->
        TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
         modifier = Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[selectedIndex])
        )
       }
      ){
       tabs.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        val selected = (selectedIndex == index)
        Tab(
         selected = selected,
         onClick = {
          selectedIndex = index
          scope.launch{
           lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(selectedIndex)
          }
          },
         text = {
          Text(color = if(lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex == index) white else red
          }
        )
       }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I just solved it.

Just set the tabPositions[lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex]

Note: This will actually cause an error: https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/checks/FrequentlyChangedStateReadInComposition.md.html

"Frequently changing state should not be directly read in composable function"

But putting a @SuppressWarnings("FrequentlyChangedStateReadInComposition")